# Python. Get {key:value} from dictionary in list and set it to another dict in list

Tags: python, dictionary

I was researching answer for my question, but I have not found a solution.
I have two lists. Elements of the lists are dictionaries. I want to get `key:value` from first list only if a dictionary has equal another `key:value`.
Example:

```
list_1 = [{'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}, {'A':10, 'B':20, 'C':30}]
list_2 = [{'A':1, 'B':22,}, {'A':111, 'B':20}]

# I need get key and value of 'C' from list_1 IF value of 'A' in both dict are equal

# code block for my task...

# result
list_2 = [{'A':1, 'B':22, 'C':3}, {'A':111, 'B':20}]

# 'C':3 append in list_2[0], because 'A' has same value
```

UPD:
It should be working even if dict with the same value of 'A' has different indices:

```
list_1 = [{'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}, {'A':10, 'B':20, 'C':30}]
list_2 = [{'A':111, 'B':20}, {'A':1, 'B':22,}]

# code...

# result
list_2 = [{'A':111, 'B':20}, {'A':1, 'B':22, 'C':3}]
```

Comment: So you group by `A`? It is not entirely clear to me what you want...

Comment: Furthermore what should happen if two dicts of `list_1` share a key?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem 
1. Check value of `'A'` in every dict (comparison dict of `list_1` and dict of `list_2`)
2. If value of `'A'` from dict in `list_2` equal to value of `'A'` in dict in `list_1`
3. Get another `key:value` (for example, `'C':3`) from dict in `list_1` and append it to appropriate dict in `list_2`

P.S. Sorry, if I explain not clearly enough, but I can't better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i get it right this is what you want

```
list_1 = [{'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}, {'A':10, 'B':20, 'C':30}]
list_2 = [{'A':1, 'B':22,}, {'A':111, 'B':20}]

for dic in range(len(list_1)):
  if list_1[dic]['A']==list_2[dic]['A']:
    list_2[dic]['C']=list_1[dic]['C']
print(list_2)
```

out:
`[{'A': 1, 'B': 22, 'C': 3}, {'A': 111, 'B': 20}]`

UPDATE: I implemented as a function and added the functionality you want,check if it ok..

```
def add_to_other_list(list_1,list_2):
  for dic_1 in list_1:
    for dic_2 in list_2:
      if dic_1['A']==dic_2['A']:
        dic_2['C']=dic_1['C']
  return list_2

list_2 = add_to_other_list(list_1,list_2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working if dic have different indices. For example, if `list_2[1]` have `'A':1`  and `list_1[0]` have `'A':1`

Comment: if list_2[1] have 'A':1 and list_1[0] have 'A':1 what should be the output??

Comment: I have updated my ask and add output for this case. Please, see it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner, which assumes that the key A is in all dicts in `list_1` and `list_2` and C in all dicts of `list_1`:

```
list_2 = [dict(l2, C=l1['C']) if l1['A'] == l2['A'] else l1 for l1, l2 in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

Comment: (1) you cannot add dictionaries together; and (2) here you hardcode `C` and make the assumption that `A` and `B` are always in the dictionaries.

Comment: (1) True... don't know what got into me. (2) yes, those are the assumptions... I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
def copymatch (matchkey, copykey, source, target):
    if source.get(matchkey) == target.get(matchkey):
        target[copykey] = source.get(copykey)

for source, target in zip(list_1,list_2):
    copymatch('A','C',source,target)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working if appropriate dictionaries have different indices. Please, see updated info in my ask